# Make a Connect and Disconnect button in VSB

Tags: .net

I'm new to programming with VSB,and can't seem to figure this issue out.

I have a basic program that will Connect and Disconnect to a users airplane. For now, if you enter the callsign "VIR12E" into the textbox and hit the "Connect" button, the "Connect" text turns into "Disconnect".

What I want to do now is make the disconnect button work, to where when you click the "Disconnect" button, the text turns back into "Connect".

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click
    If textBoxMessage.Text = "VIR12E" Then
        Connect.Text = "Disconnected"
    ElseIf trim(textBoxMessage.Text & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring Then
        Connect.Text = "Connect"
        Instructions.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click
    Connect.Text = "Connect"
End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting below error:

```
 'Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
```

Comment: the error message looks pretty self explanatory : `Connect_Click(Object, EventArgs)` is defined twice, so you need to get rid of one definition.

Comment: I understand, but I'm asking how I would add my needed function without defining it twice

Comment: What do you mean by "add my needed function" ? There is already a function, defining it twice makes no sense to me.

Comment: I need to add a function that basically says "When I click this button that says Disconnect, the text on the button turns to Connect"

Comment: then you should do that in a single function, add a test "if the button says Disconnect, then set it to Connect"

Comment: That's my question...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click
    If Connect.Text = "Connect" Then
        If textBoxMessage.Text = "VIR12E" Then
            Connect.Text = "Disconnect"
        End If
    Else
        'Put your disconnect logic here (empty the textbox, show instructions or something)
        Connect.Text = "Connect"
    End If
End Sub
```

And remove the other Connect_Click definition. This If-structure can be simplified but I guess you'll have some more logic in there.